# Merge sort gives poor efficiency and isn't affected by compiler optimizations

Tags: sorting, visual-c++

While trying to measure the time various sorting algorithms require to sort a random array of unsigned integers, I've obtained some peculiar behavior regarding top-down Merge sort that doesn't seem to be caused by bad implementation.

On arrays of length up to 1 million values, Merge sort behaves a lot worst than random-pivot Quicksort and even Shell sort. This is unexpected so I've tried with multiple online implementations of Merge sort but the result still seems to be about the same.

[Graph 1, optimizations ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5LXr.jpg)

This is the implementation I used for these graphs:

```
void merge(int *array, int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k, nl, nr;
    nl = m - l + 1; nr = r - m;
    int *larr = new int[nl], *rarr = new int[nr];

    for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
        larr[i] = array[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < nr; j++)
        rarr[j] = array[m + 1 + j];

    i = 0; j = 0; k = l;
    while (i < nl && j < nr) {
        if (larr[i] <= rarr[j]) {
            array[k] = larr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            array[k] = rarr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < nl) {
        array[k] = larr[i];
        i++; k++;
    }
    while (j < nr) {
        array[k] = rarr[j];
        j++; k++;
    }

    delete[] larr;
    delete[] rarr;
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, l, m);
        mergeSort(array, m + 1, r);
        merge(array, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

I have also tried to remove compiler optimizations (VisualC++15), favoring size instead of speed and this seem to have affected all the other algorithms instead of Merge sort. Nonetheless, it still got the worst time.

[Graph 2, optimizations OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3tL9.jpg)

The only time Merge sort didn't give the worst time was on a test with arrays of 15 million elements where it got just a slightly better performance than Heap sort, but still far from the others.

The values that I plot are the averages of 100 tests with random arrays so I don't think this is just a particular case. I also don't think the use of dynamic memory in Merge sort is the cause of these results, 16GB of RAM are plenty for these tests and everything else.

Does anybody know why Merge sort behaves so badly and why compiler optimizations don't seem to affect Merge sort?

Comment: What happens to performance if - instead of allocating, using, and freeing two scratch buffers in each `merge` - you allocate two global scratch buffers up front, same size as the input array, and use those instead? --- If you need reentrance, and who doesn't, the buffers will need to be passed in as parameters, of course.

Comment: This does indeed increase the performance significantly and it gives a better compiler optimization. Thank you for your input!